# How can I highlight complete words with keywords with regexp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a longer text and some keywords. I want to highlight these keywords in my text. That is no problem with this code:

```
        private static string HighlightKeywords2(string keywords, string text)
        {
            // Swap out the ,<space> for pipes and add the braces
            Regex r = new Regex(@", ?");
            keywords = "(" + r.Replace(keywords, @"|") + ")";

            // Get ready to replace the keywords
            r = new Regex(keywords, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // Do the replace
            return r.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(MatchEval2));
        }


        private static string MatchEval2(Match match)
        {
            if (match.Groups[1].Success)
            {
                return "<b>" + match.ToString() + "</b>";
            }

            return ""; //no match
        }
```

But when the word"tournament" is in the text and the keyword "tour" it becomes `<b>tour</b>nament`. I want to it to highlight the complete word: `<b>tournament</b>`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `\w*` before and after each keyword. That way, the entire word would match if it contains a keyword.

**Edit:** In your code,

```
keywords = "(\\w*" + r.Replace(keywords, @"\w*|\w*") + "\\w*)";
```

should do it.

Comment: Just had to add one more backslash: keywords = "(\\w*" + r.Replace(keywords, @"\w*|\w*") + "\\w*)";